# navigating from one page to another in

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

I am creating WP plugin and navigate to another page when user clicks on a button.

```
echo '<form name="coup" action="/DbForm.php" >';
         echo '<input type="submit" value="Add new Cities" />';
    echo '</form>';
```

when i click on the link it goes to my

```
Site_address/wp-admin/DbForm.php?
```

What is the reason behind this.Can you tell me the reason?

Comment: Only because you personally use PHP version 5.3 this must not make the question PHP 5.3 specific. Normally it's enough you tag it with PHP to show which language it relates to. There is nothing PHP 5.3 specific with it anyway.

Comment: Also your question is not clear. The code you've posted does not contain any link. Please make this more clear and add the HTML code you have in the browser for "that link", too. Navigating form one page to another should be likely explained somewhere as well, because it is a pretty basic principle, therefore you should make clear what the roadblock is for you to just solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are submitting an empty form which has its action at `/DbForm.php`.
Why can't you use a simple `<a>` element?

```
<a href="/DbForm.php">Add new Cities</a>
```

Comment: @user1765876, yeah, that's the point. A *link* is supposed to point the user to another page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript:
http://html-bin.appspot.com/aghodG1sLWJpbnIMCxIEUGFnZRiu5UkM

Hope I've helped.